# How to clear results using JMenuItem

Tags: java, jmenuitem

What code do I use for the `JMenuItem` *Clear* in order to clear results from the memory in Java GUI appliation? I know how to clear from a `JText` field, by using the `object.setText("");`, but how do I clear results using a `JMenuItem`?

Comment: what do you mean by "results" ? Do you mean menu items ?

Comment: I'm making a Car Care gui business application and the user has choices to select a type of oil change and or a car wash, but there's an option to select the Total amount for services selected, and an option to select "Clear" to clear the results selected and select service for another customer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, so I'll try and answer what I think your asking...

### Removing from a List using JMenuItems

Remove things from somewhere else in response to clicking on the JMenuItem:

Item class:

```
public class Item {
     public static final String name;
     public static int cost;

     public Item(String name, int cost) {
         this.name = name;
         this.int = int;
     }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main() {
        List<Item> list = new LinkedList<>();

        JMenu menu = new JMenu();
        menu.add( new JMenuItem(
            new AbstractAction("Add Carwash") {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   list.add( new Item("CarWash", 10) );
               }
            }
        );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem(
            new AbstractAction("Oil Change") {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   list.add( new Item("Oil Change", 10) );
               }
            }
        );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem(
            new AbstractAction("Clear") {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   list.clear();
               }
            }
        );
        menu.add( new JMenuItem(
            new AbstractAction("Total") {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   System.out.println(
                       list.stream().mapToInt().sum()
                   );
               }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Note that this is not complete, may not not compile, and does not actually display anything yet (add the menu to a JFrame).

Comment: Maybe this is more clearer:
Your manager wants you to create a prototype Java application using menus that will calculate the cost of a customer getting an oil change, car wash, or both. This application should add the appropriate amount to the total cost when services are provided. When the total menu item is selected, a message box should display the services purchased and the total amount. Allow the client to use the clear menu item to wipe out the memory and start fresh for a new customer. The exit menu item should close the application.

Comment: The only thing I need to do is to be able to use the "Clear" menu item to wipe out the memory and start fresh for a new customer. I do not need to remove the menu item, but I only need to be able to use the "Clear" menu item to wipe out the memory and start fresh for a new customer.

Comment: What is the "memory" exactly? A List of items selected? An integer storing the total cost? If so, item three would seem closest to what you want - just change "textfield.setText("")" to something like "list.clear()" or "total_cost = 0", depending on how you are storing the selected results.

Comment: This items would be the cost of an oil change, car wash, and the total amount for those services selected. And then, I would have to clear those services and the total amount so that I can put in a new service for a new client.

The only thing that I need to do is to clear an order so that I can make a new order instead of hitting the "Exit" menu item to close the program and reopening it back up to put in a new order.

Comment: For example, I used this code for exit:
if (event.getSource() == exitItem)
   {
    System.exit(0);
   }

This is what I have so far for the clearItem:

if (event.getSource() == clearItem)
   {
    //What code goes here
   }

I have no JTextField at all. The program doesn't call for any text fields.